# Angular Renderer invokeElementMethod throws object ErrorEvent in Jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I need to focus an input element and select all text on clicking of another element. To do this I am using the @ViewChild to get the input element and pass it inside renderer invokeElementMethod.

The code in component goes as below,

```
setTimeout(() => {
         this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elAccountRename.nativeElement, 'select', []);
         this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elAccountRename.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
      }, 0);
```

The functionality works fine from component level.Now, when I try to write test cases to execute the method where the above code is executed it throws

```
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

My test case block is as below,

```
  component.onEditClick(mock);
  expect(component.isAccountNameInvalid).toBe(false);
  expect(mock.isEditInProcess).toBe(true);
  spyOn(component, 'onEditClick');
  setTimeout(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.elAccountRename.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
  }, 0);
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the timeout of your test ? Try with 2 seconds, and reduce it until it stops to work. (I usually add 200 to 500ms).

Comment: No still the same issue. :(

Comment: And since you have the nativeElement reference and you're not changing the dom, why don't you call `focus` directly on it ?

Comment: Its also returning the same error. I tried dirct invoke of focus from component and tried component.elAccountRename.nativeElement.focus() from spec. Hope thats what you meant and its still failing...

Comment: I meant in the component directly. But `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` comes from timeout issues, I usually get in when I mock my services and I return a value too fast. That's all i can tell you without a [mcve], sorry ...

Comment: But I think in this case it might not be the timeout because the element is defined not throwing undefined and the block does execute. Not sure the way i am invoking the event itself from spec file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it completely fits your problem, but I was running into a similar problem where jasmine would throw a timeout error:

```
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

or

```
Timeout has occurred thrown
```

in IDE output.

In my case, the error was caused by a test case that asynchronously called service methods that I forgot to mock (and which failed to return during unit testing).

The according timeouts are thrown after jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL ms. Karma then wrongly associates them to the currently executing test case, which usually is one that comes after the one that caused the timeout. This was very misleading to me.

In order to identify the real root cause test case I wrote a placeholder test case:

```
it('just waits', (done) => {
  sleep(4000).then(() => { // sleept time needs to be lower than default timeout
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    done();
  })
});
```

which I moved through the test suite. Depending on where you put it, you will see different tests fail. The moment you see a difference you know that there are issues with test cases before.